# Codename One - Creating json file/text from data

Tags: java, json, parsing, escaping, codenameone

My Android app handles json files, that is, writes and reads them, to have a json version of some structures in memory (load/save).
I am porting it by means of Codename One.

This is what I have for reading the json into the memory structure:

```
public void buildDataFromJSON()
{

    JSONParser json = new JSONParser();
    try(Reader r = new InputStreamReader(Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(),JSON_FILE_NAME),
            "UTF-8");) {
        Map<String, Object> jsonData = json.parseJSON(r);
        data.field1=(String)jsonData.get(FIELD1_NAME);
        data.field2=(int)jsonData.get(FIELD2_NAME);
    }
    catch (IOError exc)

    {

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }


 }
```

I do not even know if it works because I need to create the file first.

I used to exploit JSON imports in my Android app. For example:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

But the ide says I have to find the jar on the web. I think this would not be cross-platform.

I would like to know how to create the json file from the data. I also need the json text, not only to be written on file, in certain cases.

I mean, do I have to write just the text with delimiters and putting the escaped strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you shouldn't just download or import a jar. Instead open Codename One Settings and find [this library](https://github.com/shannah/CN1JSON).

It's pretty compatible with the Android JSON parsing code but has different imports if I remember correctly. Once you use that you can reuse your code.

Codename One also has a builtin JSON parser and [property objects](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties-are-amazing.html) but you don't need to use them if you already have JSON parsing logic.

Comment: What are the advantages / differences between the cn1lib you linked in the answer and JSONParser class integrated in CN1?

Comment: It's to support existing Android/Java code that uses that syntax. I don't think it has a real advantage other than compatibility